Using MessageDlg in Delphi FireMonkey for Android
In Delphi FireMonkey for Android, when I use
MessageDlg('unknown', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);

I get errors. How should I use MessageDlg in FireMonkey?
I need to show MessageDlg like this:
MessageDlg('delete user', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0);

What is the proper way to do this?

You write: "show me Erors" without telling what the message tells you. Always when you get an error message, copy that error message (as text, never as an image) to your question. Saying that you get an error, without telling what the error message is, is not nice to people that try to help you. As you are working on a Firemonkey project, the error is probably related to the incompatibility of the Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg.

MsgDialog is deprecated, as explained by its help page, and on Android it is 'non-blocking', which means that when you call it, your program continues without waiting for the user to respond to it.  It says that you should use Platform.IFMXDialogServiceAsync.MessageDialogAsync instead.

The help page is here: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Dialogs.MessageDlg (I couldn't locate it before, thanks to RSS 544, which provided the workaround).

While some of the comments are helpful, none of them answer your question.  The FMX version of MessageDlg require that the enumerations for the dialog type and button(s) to be fully qualified.  In other words SCOPEDENUMS is ON for those types.
The proper syntax is:
MessageDlg('delete user', TMsgDlgType.mtWarning, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0);

